# Crystal Reports Select only Unique ID

Tags: crystal-reports, duplicates, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report that is pulling an ID field. I want to use the select expert to say if an ID is duplicated, do not pull this data. I know I can use format field, suppress if duplicated, but I don't want the data to be pulled in the first place, if possible.

How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can do this by using an sql query as a command table rather than directly querying the database with Crystal

Comment: So you're saying I could do that and use Select Distinct {mytable} and add it that way? I've never used a SQL command in a Crystal report.

Comment: In database label you have `Select distinct records`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below listed solutions. I usually try one by one of this solution, because different issue may have different solution. But so far, I can say that most of duplicate issue solve by query (last solution)

1) checkbox suppress if duplicate
2) Distinct
3) Grouping
3) SQL Query (The best)